# Need copy and paste daily macro that shifts right to next column after each paste

Tags: vba, excel

Hi guys i have a small problem i need help with.

I am copying data from Worksheet 1 , cell range B1:B21 and pasting into worksheet 2, cell range C4:C25.

After i paste in the data i want to move across one column to the right ,

here is my code so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Workbooks("COPY Service Tracker  August  2016.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B21").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Queue Performance").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Select


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

         Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

So the code has gotten me as far as pasting the correct data into where i want it.
now when i go to run this macro again tomorrow the data that is copied is different to yesterdays data because it is updated daily as well.
i want to paste this new data in the next column over from yesterday while keeping the data from yesterday where it is.

The data is being entered into columns with the headers as dates so i am saving the new daily data or each day.
Thank you

Comment: In terms of performance of your code, you want to try and avoid copy & paste wherever possible. Set the value of cells to be the value of others. e.g. `Range("A1").Value = Range("B2").Value`. In terms of moving to the right / left / up / down you need to look into `Offset`.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `.End(xlToLeft)` method of `Range` object in conjunction to `.Cells(4, .Columns.Count)` in order to get the actual last non empty cell in row 4

then avoid using `Select`/`Selection` and `Activate`/`ActiveXXX` which can both  have significant speed issues and mostly lead to loose control over what workbook/worksheet you're actually referencing

so you can use

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks("COPY Service Tracker  August  2016.xlsm")
    With wb.Worksheets("Queue Performance")
        .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 21).value = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B21").value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @sullkid16: did you try this?

Comment: @sullkid16: it'd be nice of you to give feedbakcs to people trying and help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.End(xlToRight)` to find the right most cell and use `.Offset(0,1)` to reference the next column (which will be blank). e.g.:

```
Workbooks("COPY Service Tracker  August  2016.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B21").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Queue Performance").Select

ActiveSheet.Range("A4").End(xlToRight).Offset(0,1).Select


Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

(Assumes that columns A onwards are filled)

Comment: Thank you, I think this has solved it but will need to run some test first.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Tim in the comments, it is highly recommended to avoid `.Select`, `.Copy` and `.Paste`. I'd also suggest using `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook` as it helps when debugging. By setting the ranges you will make the process quicker and less error-prone:

```
Dim ws1, ws2 as Worksheet
Dim lCol as Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Queue Performance")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("COPY Service Tracker  August  2016.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")

lCol = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
lRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlup).Row

ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, lCol), ws1.Cells(lRow, lCol)).Value = _
ws2.Range("B1:B" & lRow).Value
```

`lCol` is the last next column to populate in the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Queue Performance")` worksheet and `lRow` is the last row to be copied from the `Workbooks("COPY Service Tracker  August  2016.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")` worksheet.

Comment: i am getting a compile error with the above code. the last 2 lines are highlighted red

Comment: I am now getting an error 1004 and the debug is pointing to the last two lines again

Comment: Sorry, there was an extra `Range(` in there, this has now been removed.

Comment: ok those errors are now gone, is this the full solution to my problem ? the macro doesnt seem to change anything?